# Kubernetes Deployment Patch API is not deleting old ReplicaSets

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud-private, kubernetes-deployment

I am using Kubernetes API v1.9 to patch my deployments, but after the patch, the old replicaset are not removed, and I cannot see 'OldReplicaSets' using kubectl describe deploy xxx. I cannot roll back to old versions as well.

Cluster Information

- IBM ICP v2.1.0.2, Kubernetes V1.9
- IBM ICP v2.1.0.3, Kubernetes V1.10

Kubectl Version:
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.1", GitCommit:"3a1c9449a956b6026f075fa3134ff92f7d55f812", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-01-04T11:52:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.1+icp-ee", GitCommit:"d97ba3f083461e0ae0a8881550e83350af4c8f57", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-02-23T07:20:41Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

The API address :
https://v1-9.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.9/#patch-22

The API call I made with Postman:

```
PATCH /apis/apps/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/devops-front HTTP/1.1
Host: ****:8001
Content-Type: application/strategic-merge-patch+json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 46052a2c-2f3b-48a0-83b9-c70aeb2e5dda

{
    "metadata": {
        "labels": {
            "version":"v1.0.7"
        }
    },
    "spec": {
        "template": {
            "spec": {
                "containers": [{
                    "name": "devops-front",
                    "image": "mycluster.icp:8500/default/devops/devops-front:v1.0.7"
                }]
            },
            "metadata": {
                "labels": {
                    "version": "v1.0.7"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The deploy information after the request:

```
Name:                   devops-front
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Tue, 28 Aug 2018 10:07:52 +0800
Labels:                 run=devops-front
                        version=v1.0.0
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision=1
Selector:               run=devops-front,version=v1.0.7
Replicas:               3 desired | 3 updated | 3 total | 3 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  run=devops-front
           version=v1.0.7
  Containers:
   devops-front:
    Image:        mycluster.icp:8500/default/devops/devops-front:v1.0.7
    Ports:        80/TCP, 443/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   devops-front-655c4969b4 (3/3 replicas created)
Events:          <none>
```

I give some more details here

My yaml file: The version label and the tag of the image is automatically refined by code.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: devops-front
spec:
  replicas: 3
  strategy: 
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: devops-front
        version: v1.0.7
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: devops-front
        image: mycluster.icp:8500/default/devops/devops-front:v1.0.7
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443  
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

When I use the HTTP PATCH API to update my deployment, I get two ReplicaSet:

```
NAME                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
devops-front-5c4b55bf96             3         3         3         6h
devops-front-c98d99cf6              3         3         3         2d
```

These two replicasets differs only in the version label and image version. As I described, the old ReplicaSet is not deleted as expected, neither do I see a rolling update process after calling the patch api.

- Why don't I use replace api?

Because I learned that kubernetes has RollingUpdate feature, and I don't want my application down during the update. I know I could use kubectl set image to change my version, but I also want to change the label. As far as I know, I should use kubectl patch deployments/devops-front ... to make changes. The problem here is that kubectl patch doesn't equal to the patch rest api.

- Why don't I use kubectl?

Because sometimes I don't have kubectl installed. For example, I want to patch my application in Java code,  I could simple acquire a token from the token endpoint and call Kubernetes API or use Fabric8io lib). Another example is that I want to patch my app in Jenkins Pipeline.

- Why don't I use v1.10 of kubernetes?

I have installed ICP V2.1.0.3 which is based on K8s v1.10, the same problem happens. The ReplicaSet is not automatically deleted when I call patch api.

Comment: I studied the process and it seems like you could [replace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#rolling-update) your old [deployment](https://v1-9.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment), but I am not sure yet. Please post your deployment yaml file so we can check for potential problems there, also what does the kubectl get rs show? Also please consider using the latest version, as they are more stable.